Call one of the two decision table from parent decision table in Drools DMN
I have a decision table that takes Age as an Input and returns OLD or YOUNG if Age >50 & Age <50. Based on this I need to call one of the two decision table (One for old and one of Young). How can I achieve this in Drools DMN / Kogito ?
I tried using decision table as represented in diagram. And I want this in DMN only


The diagram looks like a if/then which is definitely a design smell in the context of DMN, and more a BPMN thing.
You can achieve however analogous result in several ways.
One option, is.
Considering old vs young is a simple 1-inpudata related choice, you could just have your decision in a single table like so:
[
Another option is.
You transform your OldSpecific and YoungSpecific into BKM nodes.
Then, you have a Decision node with the following expression:
if DecideYoungOrOld = "YOUNG" then YoungSpecific(...) else OldSpecific(...)

but this is not very idiomatic DMN.
A more idiomatic way would be to transform the expression in another simple decision table:

Hope this helps. Don't forget to accept answer if helpful

Got it this should not be part of DMN

As with many things, it depends. If you wanted to model a Choice in a ~workflow, that is definitely what BPMN is for. If instead it's more part of an Evaluation, a Decision, then you can employ similar strategies as detailed.

Understood. Thank you

yea @NachiketaBG what you're doing is valid. I've done similar logic in a DMN before.
essentially: the first decision outputs a enum of value {young, old}, and the downstream decisions check for that value, such that, there is a column in the young-decision that checks that the value is "young", otherwise nothing matches in that decision. vice versa for "old" decision.
